# didBeginContact function not being called

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, swift2, collision-detection, collision

I've looked through all of the examples I could fine and nothing has been related to my issue. I have the SKPhysicsContactDelegate and I have added the self.physicsworld.contactDelegate = self. Ive pretty much done everything I could think of. Here is all the code to my project.

```
//
//  GameScene.swift
//  arrow jump
//
//  Created by Joy Cafiero on 3/29/16.
//  Copyright (c) 2016 3rd Dimension Studios inc. All rights reserved.
//

import SpriteKit

var timer = NSTimer()
var condition = 1
var arrow = SKSpriteNode()
var man = SKSpriteNode()
var bg = SKSpriteNode()
var ground = SKSpriteNode()
var buttonRight = SKSpriteNode()
var buttonLeft = SKSpriteNode()
var buttonJump = SKSpriteNode()
let moveGrounRight = SKAction.moveByX(200, y: 0, duration: 1)
let repeatMoveGroundRight = SKAction.repeatActionForever(moveGrounRight)
let moveGrounLeft = SKAction.moveByX(-200, y: 0, duration: 1)
let repeatMoveGroundLeft = SKAction.repeatActionForever(moveGrounLeft)
let runningMan1 = (SKTexture (imageNamed: "running man1.png"))
let runningMan2 = (SKTexture (imageNamed: "running man2.png"))
let runningMan3 = (SKTexture (imageNamed: "running man3.png"))
let runningMan4 = (SKTexture (imageNamed: "running man4.png"))
let runningMan5 = (SKTexture (imageNamed: "running man5.png"))
let runningMan6 = (SKTexture (imageNamed: "running man6.png"))
let nuetralMan = (SKTexture (imageNamed: "running man nuetral.png"))
let jumpingMan1 = (SKTexture (imageNamed: "jumping man1"))
let jumpingMan2 = (SKTexture (imageNamed: "jumping man2"))
let jumpingMan3 = (SKTexture (imageNamed: "jumping man3"))

let animation = SKAction.animateWithTextures([ runningMan1, runningMan2,      runningMan3,  runningMan4,  runningMan5,  runningMan6], timePerFrame: 0.15)
let jumpingAnimation = SKAction.animateWithTextures([jumpingMan1, jumpingMan2,         jumpingMan3], timePerFrame: 0.1)
let nuetralAnimation = SKAction.animateWithTextures([nuetralMan], timePerFrame: 0.05)
let repeatAnimation = SKAction.repeatActionForever(animation)

let manGroup:UInt32 = 0x1 << 1
let groundGroup:UInt32 = 0x1 << 2
let arrowGroup:UInt32 = 0x1 << 3


class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    /* Setup your scene here */

    self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self
    self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0, -5)

    man = SKSpriteNode(texture: nuetralMan)
    man.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame),     CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
    man.size = CGSize(width: man.size.width * 2, height: man.size.height * 2)
    man.zPosition = 15
    man.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: man.size)
    man.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
    man.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
    man.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = manGroup
    man.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = groundGroup | arrowGroup

    self.addChild(man)

    let bgTexture = (SKTexture(imageNamed: "wild west landscape.png"))

    bg = SKSpriteNode(texture: bgTexture)
    bg.size = CGSize(width: self.frame.width, height: self.frame.height)
    bg.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame) + 100)
    bg.zPosition = -1
    self.addChild(bg)

    let groundtexture = (SKTexture(imageNamed: "sandy ground.png"))

    ground = SKSpriteNode(texture: groundtexture)
    ground.size = CGSize(width: CGRectGetMaxX(self.frame), height: ground.size.height)
    ground.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), 0)
    ground.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: CGSizeMake(self.frame.width, ground.size.height-255))
    ground.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
    ground.zPosition = 20
    ground.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = groundGroup
    ground.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = manGroup


    self.addChild(ground)

    timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(3, target: self, selector: Selector("timerUpdate"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

    buttonRight.color = SKColor.redColor()
    buttonRight.position = CGPointMake(200, 200)
    buttonRight.size = CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)
    buttonRight.zPosition = 25

    self.addChild(buttonRight)

    buttonLeft.color = SKColor.redColor()
    buttonLeft.position = CGPointMake(100, 200)
    buttonLeft.size = CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)
    buttonLeft.zPosition = 25

    self.addChild(buttonLeft)

    buttonJump.color = SKColor.greenColor()
    buttonJump.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMaxX(self.frame) - 200, 200)
    buttonJump.size = CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)
    buttonJump.zPosition = 25

    self.addChild(buttonJump)


}

func timerUpdate() {
    let random = Int(arc4random_uniform(3))
    var timeIncrease:NSTimeInterval = 0
    var randomArrow = [self.frame.height / 20 + CGRectGetMidY(self.frame) - 65, self.frame.height / 20 + self.frame.height / 20 + CGRectGetMidY(self.frame) - 65, self.frame.height / 20 + self.frame.height / 20 + self.frame.height / 20 + CGRectGetMidY(self.frame) - 65, self.frame.height / 20 + self.frame.height / 20 + self.frame.height / 20 + CGRectGetMidY(self.frame) - 65]
    timeIncrease = timeIncrease + 7
    let arrowTexture = (SKTexture(imageNamed: "arrow.png"))
    let movingArrow = SKAction.moveByX(-self.frame.size.width, y: 0, duration: 10-timeIncrease)
    let removeArrows = SKAction.removeFromParent()
    let repeatmoveArrows = SKAction.sequence([movingArrow, removeArrows])
    arrow = SKSpriteNode(texture: arrowTexture)
    arrow.size = CGSize(width: arrow.size.width, height: arrow.size.height)
    arrow.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMaxX(self.frame), randomArrow[random])
    arrow.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: CGSizeMake(arrowTexture.size().width - 100, arrow.size.height / 2))
    arrow.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
    arrow.zPosition = 10
    arrow.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = arrowGroup
    arrow.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = manGroup
    arrow.runAction(repeatmoveArrows)

    self.addChild(arrow)

}


override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
   /* Called when a touch begins */
    for touch: AnyObject in touches {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
        if buttonRight.containsPoint(location) {
            man.xScale = 1
            man.runAction(repeatMoveGroundRight, withKey: "MoveRight")
            man.runAction(repeatAnimation, withKey: "Run")
        }

        if buttonLeft.containsPoint(location) {
            man.xScale = -1
            man.runAction(repeatMoveGroundLeft, withKey: "MoveLeft")
            man.runAction(repeatAnimation, withKey: "Run")
        }

        if buttonJump.containsPoint(location) {
            if(condition == 1) {
            man.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVectorMake(0, 0)
            man.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVectorMake(0, 400))
            man.runAction(jumpingAnimation)
                condition = 0
            }
        }


}
}

override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        for touch: AnyObject in touches {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
        if buttonRight.containsPoint(location) {
            man.removeActionForKey("MoveRight")
            man.removeActionForKey("Run")
            man.texture = nuetralMan
        }
        if buttonLeft.containsPoint(location) {
            man.removeActionForKey("MoveLeft")
            man.removeActionForKey("Run")
            man.texture = nuetralMan
        }

    }
}


override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch: AnyObject in touches {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
        if buttonRight.containsPoint(location) {
            man.removeActionForKey("MoveRight")
            man.removeActionForKey("Run")
            man.texture = nuetralMan
        }
        if buttonLeft.containsPoint(location) {
            man.removeActionForKey("MoveLeft")
            man.removeActionForKey("Run")
            man.texture = nuetralMan
        }

    }

    func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {

        var firstBody: SKPhysicsBody
        var secondBody: SKPhysicsBody
        var thirdBody: SKPhysicsBody

        if contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask < contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask {
            firstBody = contact.bodyA
            secondBody = contact.bodyB
        } else {
            firstBody = contact.bodyB
            secondBody = contact.bodyA
        }

        if contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask < contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask {
            firstBody = contact.bodyA
            thirdBody = contact.bodyB
        } else {
            firstBody = contact.bodyB
            thirdBody = contact.bodyA
        }


        if firstBody.categoryBitMask == manGroup || secondBody.categoryBitMask == groundGroup {
            print("contact")
            condition = 1
            man.texture = nuetralMan

        }

        if firstBody.categoryBitMask == manGroup || thirdBody.categoryBitMask == arrowGroup {
            print("dead")
        }
    }


func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
    /* Called before each frame is rendered */
}
}
}
```

I've tried to print things in the didBeginContact method but nothing happens. Ive spent 3 days trying to figure this out. Also all my categoryBitMasks and CollisionTestBitMask are set correctly as far as I know. Any help is VERY appreciated.

Comment: your arrows have a dynamic of false, so unless your man is moving into the arrow, it won't register

Comment: Yes the man has to jump over the  arrows so yes when the player messes up he will be hit by the arrow so the arrows not being dynamic is not a problem. The moveByX SKAction causes the arrows to move across the screen and the NSTimer spawns them at a 5 second rate. That is not really the problem thought the problem is that my didBeginContact function is not working and I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your definition for didBeginContact() is buried in the touchesEnded() function.  If you straighten out your bracing, it might help:

```
override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch: AnyObject in touches {
       // for touches loop (skipped)
    }
}  // Add this closing brace

    func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
        // contact body (skipped)
    }
```

And you'll also need to delete the extra brace after update():

```
// ...skipped

func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
    /* Called before each frame is rendered */
}
// }  // get rid of this one
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: wow thanks SO much dude you don't even know how much you helped me like I don't even know if I can thank you enough.  You are a true hero.